# Path created by VSTO Installer

Tags: .net, path, installation, vsto

I am developing a VSTO add-in and i have noticed that when installing it, some files are created by the VSTOInstaller itself, but I cannot find them and i need to locate those path.

One of them is: C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel[name of add-in]

Does anyone know any other path?

Answer (score 0):

The [Deploy an Office solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution?view=vs-2019) page describes all the required steps for creating an installer.

Use the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) utility to find out what files exactly are created by the VSTO installer.